# How to add custom renderer in MAUI

Tags: maui

I am trying to add a custom render in my MAUI application. I have added renderer class on my project, android and iOS platform folders.

**On Main Project:**

```cs
namespace MyApp.Renderer
{
    public class CustomEntry : Entry
    {
    }
}
```

**Android Platform:**

```cs
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MyProject.Droid.Renderer;
using MyProject.Renderer;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform;

namespace MyProject.Droid.Renderer
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        public CustomEntryRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                gd.SetColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                this.Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
                this.Control.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions);
                //Control.SetHintTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(global::Android.Graphics.Color.White));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**iOS Project:**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MyProject.iOS.Renderer;
using MyProject.Renderer;
using Foundation;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.iOS;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform;
using UIKit;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
namespace MyProject.iOS.Renderer
{
    public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
                //Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
                //Control.TextColor = UIColor.White;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**On XAML:**

```xml
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Renderer"
    x:Class="MyProject.LoginPage">

    <local:CustomEntry
        x:Name="username_entry"
        Placeholder="UserName"
        ReturnType="Next"
        Keyboard="Email"/>
```

I have added this custom renderer for removing the default underline from entry. But the custom entry effect is not working after this. Anything else is pending to add for the working of custom renderer?

Comment: custom renderers are [deprecated in MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/renderer-to-handler)

Comment: Why are you not creating a handler? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/ I have a project here that you can use as an example for how to create handlers https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best results, we recommend discarding the custom render in MAUI because it is designed to consume within Xamarin.Forms.

You need create a modified mapper for the [Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.entry). See [Customize a control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize#customize-a-control). You can refer to the sample code below on how to remove the default underline for the [Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.entry) which will be applied to all the [Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.entry):

**Android:**
under Platforms/Android/MainApplication/CreateMauiApp

```
protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() { 

        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (hander, view) =>
        {
#if ANDROID
            hander.PlatformView.BackgroundTintList = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Colors.Transparent.ToAndroid());
#endif
        });

     return MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
}
```

**iOS:** under Platforms/iOS/AppDelegate/CreateMauiApp

```
 protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() { 

        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (hander, view) =>
        {
#if IOS 
           hander.PlatformView.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
#endif
        });

        return MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
}
```

Furthermore, you can [customize a specific control instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize#customize-a-specific-control-instance) of the [Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.entry), handlers for specific control instances can be customized by subclassing the control, and then by modifying the handler for the base control type only when the control is of the subclassed type.

Reference link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize#customize-a-control

Comment: Is it possible to do it with handlers? Can you show me that approach?

Comment: Yes, we can, however, the first priority is to use modified mapper. I checked your demo, you need register the handlers in the MauiProgram.cs see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/renderer-to-handler#register-the-handler

Answer (score 1):

Export Render should be removed:

```
//[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomEntry), typeof(CustomEntryRenderer))]
```

Instead, the render has to be specified in the startup.

More about here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/custom-renderers

And this guy has expertise with MSFT products and 3rd party controls:
https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/how-to-reuse-xamarin-forms-custom-renderers-in-net-maui.aspx

Anyway, this we do only if we are migrating Xamarin projects with renderers.
If we are writing something new, we use Handlers instead:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/